# Python email.utils.parsedate() alternative for french date

Tags: python, date, parsing, localization

I'd like to use [mailman archive scraper](https://github.com/philgyford/mailman-archive-scraper)

I'm facing some bugs due to the mailgun archive I'm interested in which is set with french language.

At the moment the parser use the following code :

```
message_time = time.mktime(email.utils.parsedate(soup.h1.findNextSibling('i').string))
```

I obtain a

```
TypeError: argument must be 9-item sequence, not None
```

I think this is due to **email.utils.parsedate()** function and the date in french which has this format : **Lun 17 Mar 19:30:40 CET 2014**

I'm looking for an alternative way to obtain the same parse result of email.utils.parsedate() with this date format.

My python knowledge is limited and till there I don't find.

Any idea or orientation ?

Comment: `parsedate()` supports only US dates (English + US timezones). What is your Python version? Can you install 3rd-party packages?

Comment: note: [rfc 2822 (the format parsed by `parsedate()`) does not allow french names](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2822#section-3.3)

Comment: My python version is 2.7.6. Yes I can install 3rd-party packages.
Noted for rfc 2822 does not allow french names.

Comment: What `Mar` stands for? Is it `Mardi` or `Mars`?

Comment: Yes that stands for Mars, this is day month time time-ref year.

Answer (score 0):

You could [use `dateparser` module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dateparser):

```
>>> import dateparser
>>> dateparser.parse('Lun 17 Mar 19:30:40 CET 2014')
datetime.datetime(2014, 3, 17, 19, 30, 40)
```